# Shorten path to C++ enum member (using typedef or typename), to use as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enums, typedef, shorthand

I have a rather complicated object,

```
MyNamespace::MyClass::MySubStruct
```

which has an

```
enum
{
   ONE = 1,
   TWO = 2
};
```

Now I have another class which has a template parameter

```
template <unsigned int x> class Foo;
```

Currently I initialize B as follows

```
Foo<MyNamespace::MyClass::MySubStruct::ONE> MyFoo
```

and that works just fine, but it is a bit too lengthy, especially given that I initialize this class about a hundred times.

I would like to write something like:

```
typedef MyNamespace::MyClass::MySubStruct::ONE  MyONE
Foo<MyOne> MyFoo
```

Naturally, this does not compile, and neither does declaring it as a const unsigned int inside the class. How would one do this elegantly?

Comment: If you found a solution to your question, post it as an answer. (And if someone else posted the solution, mark their answer as accepted instead) Do not edit it into the question. :)

Comment: thank you jalf, sorry I did not know the rules yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enumerators are values, not types. If you only need this particular enumerator, declare a constant:

```
const auto MyONE = MyNamespace::MyClass::MySubStruct::ONE;
```

If you need more than only this one, it could be feasible to add a typedef for `MySubStruct` and access the enumerators through that.

Answer (score 2):

`ONE` isn't a type; it's a value.

Instead of using `typedef`, you could simply use a constant:

```
const auto MyONE = MyNamespace::MyClass::MySubStruct::ONE;
```

Consider also using `enum class` instead of `enum`.